# Remove suffix of a Domain in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm working on tons of URLs and I need to remove the suffix of a URL. I used LEFT function but it can only remove .org, .net, .com or any other 3 letter suffix. My problem is, there are also websites that has 2 letter suffix:

> http://www.howtouseseo.com/health/resources  -> howtouseseo
>
> http://www.hpa.nhs.uk/Topics/InfectiousDiseases/InfectiousDiseasesLinks/  -> hpa
>
> http://hpani.org/Links/smokingcessation.htm  -> hpani
>
> http://www.hpcbd.com/Resources.html  -> hpcbd
>
> http://hpp.lipscomb.edu/healthcenter/Health-Resources  -> hpp.lipscomb
>
> http://www.hpsdma.nic.in/UsefulLinks.html  -> hpsdma

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: According to your examples, you just want the second part of the dotted name. What about google.com, google.oc.nz. If you want a full solution, post all of the real world examples.

Comment: Hi! I edited the post to real website samples.

Comment: `RegEx` will make short work of this. Off the top of my head, though. that `hpp.lipscomb` is going to present some problems even in `RegEx`.

Comment: agree with BK201 "that `hpp.lipscomb` is going to present some problems". That's what i've mentioned as well in my post :) you can still try what PatricK provided though. I'll try to check if there's a workaround but i'm lost atm.

Comment: The function provided by PatricK worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only interested in the 2nd part of the URL, write a function in a module and use it in the sheet

```
Public Function StripURL(oRng As Range) As String
    StripURL = Split(oRng.Value, ".")(1)
End Function
```

[image: dataset1]

**UPDATE**

```
Public Function StripURL(oRng As Range) As String
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = oRng.Value
    ' 1. Keep text after "//"
    If InStr(1, sURL, "//", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then sURL = Split(sURL, "//")(1)
    ' 2. Keep text before first "/"
    sURL = Split(sURL, "/")(0)
    ' 3. Check if contains "www."
    If InStr(1, sURL, "www.", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' 3a. Remove "www."
        sURL = Replace(sURL, "www.", "")
        ' 4. Check number of dots
        Select Case UBound(Split(sURL, "."))
            Case 0 To 2
                sURL = Split(sURL, ".")(0)
            Case Is > 2
                sURL = Split(sURL, ".")(0) & "." & Split(sURL, ".")(1)
        End Select
    Else
        ' 3b. Check number of dots
        Select Case UBound(Split(sURL, "."))
            Case 0 To 1
                sURL = Split(sURL, ".")(0)
            Case Is > 1
                sURL = Split(sURL, ".")(0) & "." & Split(sURL, ".")(1)
        End Select
    End If
    StripURL = sURL
End Function
```

[image: dataset2]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! But this didn't work for websites without www. at the beginning. Here are the sample websites I tried it, sorry for not using this websites in the post! I already edit it.

This is where it had a problem:

> http://hpani.org/Links/smokingcessation.htm  -> org/Links/smokingcessation

Answer (score 0):

If your entry is as simple as what your example is, you can try this:

```
=MID(MID(A1,12,LEN(A1)-11),1,SEARCH(".",MID(A1,12,LEN(A1)-11))-1)
```

Assuming your data is arranged like this:

[image]

If however, you have extra dots in between, then this will not 100% work.
Hope this hepls you a bit.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! Like the other answer, this didn't work for websites without www. at the beginning. Here are the sample websites I tried it, sorry for not using this websites in the post! I already edit it. This is where it had a problem: > hpani.org/Links/smokingcessation.htm